# UPDATE MySQL table using php loop

Tags: mysql

Given the following mysql table, here I attach a sample:

```
+------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| f_id | sub_id    | field_name  | field_val         |
+------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| 256  | 15        | Email:      | pete@abba.com     |
| 257  | 15        | Name:       | Peter             |
| 258  | 15        | Page:       | home/contact.html |
| 259  | 16        | Email:      | john@xyz.com      |
| 260  | 16        | Name:       | John              |
| 261  | 16        | Page:       | page-example.html |
| 262  | 17        | Email:      | mary@cococo.net   |
| 263  | 17        | Name:       | Mary              |
| 264  | 17        | Page:       | home/service.html |
+------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

I need to evaluate the `field_val` value when `field_name LIKE 'Email:'` and get the company name, comparing the email extension using an existing array that stores the relation between mail extensions and company names:

```
array(
'abba.com' => 'Abba INC.',
'xyz.com' => 'Xyz S.A.',
'cococo.net' => 'Cococo Ltd.'
);
```

And convert the first table in the following table:

```
+------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| f_id | sub_id    | field_name  | field_val         |
+------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| 256  | 15        | Email:      | pete@abba.com     |
| 257  | 15        | Name:       | Peter             |
| 258  | 15        | Company:    | Abba INC.         |
| 259  | 16        | Email:      | john@xyz.com      |
| 260  | 16        | Name:       | John              |
| 261  | 16        | Company:    | Xyz S.A.          |
| 262  | 17        | Email:      | mary@cococo.net   |
| 263  | 17        | Name:       | Mary              |
| 264  | 17        | Company:    | Cococo Ltd.       |
+------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

So, I have to change the `field_name` value of `Page:` to `Company:`, without changing `f_id`, and assign the `field_val` corresponding value, obtained through the mentioned array.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change the field_name Page:, or add a new record Company: for each Email:? If you just want to add a new field_name record for each, it can be done with a single SQL statement. Actually, either can be done with a single SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate the associative array into a SQL `CASE` expression, to assign the appropriate new name based on the email in the related row.

```
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.sub_id = t2.sub_id
SET t1.field_name = 'Company:', 
    t1.field_value = CASE 
        WHEN t2.field_value LIKE '%@abba.com' THEN 'Abba, INC.'
        WHEN t2.field_value LIKE '%@xyz.com' THEN 'Xyz S.A.'
        WHEN t2.field_value LIKE '%@cococo.net' THEN 'Cococo Ltd.'
    END
WHERE t1.field_name = 'Page:'
AND t2.field_name = 'Email:'
AND (t2.field_value LIKE '%@abba.com' 
    OR t2.field_value LIKE '%@xyz.com'
    OR t2.field_value LIKE '%@cococo.net')
```

In PHP you can construct the query dynamically:

```
$cases = array();
$likes = array();
foreach ($array as $domain => $company) {
    $cases[] = "WHEN t2.field_value LIKE '%@$domain' THEN '$company'";
    $likes[] = "t2.field_value LIKE '%@$domain'";
}
$cases_string = implode(' ', $cases);
$likes_string = implode(' OR ', $likes);
$sql = "UPDATE yourTable AS t1
        JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t1.sub_id = t2.sub_id
        SET t1.field_name = 'Company:', 
            t1.field_value = CASE $cases_string END
        WHERE t1.field_name = 'Page:'
        AND t2.field_name = 'Email:'
        AND ($likes_string)";
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but the CASE expression will have 200 lines in order to cover all the possibilities... For this I thought that maybe is better to pass the CASE through a `foreach` php loop... But I don't know how to properly combine SQL and PHP...

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was thinking about... Many thanks @Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

I think in the second table you would be altering the value of the "f_id" column. I think you should first evaluate if this column is auto incrementable, since what you need to do is add a record after "Name:" in a match called "Company", is not it? In any case that "f_id" is not auto incrementable the thing would be much easier.

On the other hand, I would tell you to solve it in three possible ways:

1. Truncate the table completely and re-insert the new records after successfully traversing your array through "php". This would be a later solution but effective in case you are working on the camp "f_id" a value, as I said before, self incrementable.
2. If the "f_id" column is not auto incrementable, you will have to save all records after the match found (including the last ID). Having this, you will have to delete them and then insert the "Company". Following this, you're going to have to re-update your table to insert the records you deleted.
3. If you find a match, I recommend you save the value of "f_id" in some table called, for example, "companies", where you store some "id" that you consider can relate directly to a company. In this case yes I will recommend you to investigate on the subject of relational databases.

Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This should update the email records to company records. It does require that your array be in a table.

```
UPDATE `fields` f
SET `field_name` = `new_field_name`, 
    `field_val` =  (SELECT 
        c.`company_name`
    FROM `companies` c 
    WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(f.`field_val`,LOCATE('@',f.`field_val`) + 1,100)) = LOWER(c.`company_email`))
    AND f.`field_name` = 'Email:')
WHERE `field_name` = 'Email:'
```